# c++ Win32 Api GetMessage closing program inside thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi, getmessage

I'm building a interface using the win32 api and I wanted to manage all the suff in another class with a thread to keep doing work in the main.
I have this code:

**WindowManager.h**

```
class UIManager::WindowManager {
private:
    //Class data
    HINSTANCE hInstance;
    WNDCLASSEX winClass; /* Data structure for the windowclass */
    MSG msg;
    HWND hwnd;
    //Window Data
    LPCSTR wiName;
    int startX = 250;
    int startY = 150;
    int endX = 544;
    int endY = 375;
    //Private managers
    void makeWindow();
public:
    WindowManager(HINSTANCE & hInstance, std::string wiName = "Window Name");
    void show();
};
```

**WindowManager.c** (I use bind because I have the class inside a namespace and that is the only way I found that thread allows me to compile instead of throwing an error)

```
#include "WindowManager.h"

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

//Private
//
void UIManager::WindowManager::makeWindow()
{
    int ms = GetMessage(&msg, 0, 0, 0); //I do this to see if it gets to
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)) { //this part, but never happens
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
}

//Public
//
UIManager::WindowManager::WindowManager(HINSTANCE & hInstance, std::string wiName)
{
    this->wiName = wiName.c_str();
    this->hInstance = hInstance;
    winClass.cbSize = sizeof(winClass);
    winClass.hInstance = hInstance;
    winClass.lpszClassName = this->wiName;
    winClass.lpfnWndProc = WndProc; //Execution callback
    //Load default editable ellements
    winClass.hCursor = LoadCursor(0, IDC_ARROW);        /*Default*/
    winClass.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);   /*Default*/     //Alt+Tab Dialog
    winClass.hbrBackground = GetSysColorBrush(COLOR_3DFACE);
    winClass.lpszMenuName = NULL;                       /* No menu */
    RegisterClassEx(&winClass);

    //Create Window
    hwnd = CreateWindowEx(
        0,
        this->wiName,           /* Title Class */
        this->wiName,           /* Title Text */
        WS_OVERLAPPED | WS_MINIMIZEBOX | WS_SYSMENU | WS_VISIBLE | WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        startX,                         /* X Start */
        startY,                         /* Y Start */
        endX,                           /* The programs width */
        endY,                           /* and height in pixels */
        HWND_DESKTOP,                   /* The window is a child-window to desktop */
        NULL,                           /* No menu */
        hInstance,              /* Program Instance handler */
        NULL
    );
    SetWindowPos(hwnd, 0, 0, 0, 20, 20, 0);
}

void UIManager::WindowManager::show()
{
    std::thread listener(std::bind(&WindowManager::makeWindow, this));
    listener.detach();
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (msg)
    {
    case WM_CREATE:
    { //This part is executed
        //...blablabla
        break;
    }

    case WM_COMMAND:
    {//This part is never executed
        //...blablabla
        break;
    }

    case WM_DESTROY:
    {//This part is never executed
        //...blabla
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    }
    }
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

The window execute and show properly and even execute WM_CREATE, but when the "GetMessage" is executed it instantly end the program without throwing any error or something like that.

I added an int with the value of the GetMessage to see if it gets to the "while" in debug mode but it happens.
Is there a way to see the error that may be throwing or prevent it from closing the program? Or is it that I'm doing wrong calling "GetMessage" from inside a thread?

Comment: There is code missing. Can you provide a [mcve]. I'm sceptical of whether or not the arg to makeWindow is valid. I can't imagine why you would be passing a `MSG` as a reference param. My expectation would be for that to be a local variable. So, I expect your code is defective, but we can't see it.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I did so to see if it was the problem as a testing and I forgot to quit this part. I'll edit the code

Comment: Without a [mcve], we can only guess. Is it really so much to ask that you show us the code that you want help with? Did you even follow the link I gave you? If so, then do it again and read it very carefully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code has several problems:

- You create window in one thread, but try to run meesage loop in another thread. `GetMessage` only handles messages of windows belonging to the calling thread.
- You never wait for background thread processing messages and instead detach from it and continue execution in main thread probably ending application.
- You don't inspect the value returned by `GetMessage` and use it as boolean.

If you want to make background ui thread you need to move all window creation code there and call `join` on thread. And message loop should look like this:

```
::MSG msg;
for(;;)
{
    auto const res{::GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))};
    if(0 < res)
    {
        ::TranslateMessage(&msg);
        ::DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    else if(0 == res)
    {   //  PostQuitMessage was called...
        break;
    }
    else
    {   //  an error occurred...
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: The standard message loop, treating `GetMessage` as a boolean, is fine in this case: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130322-00/?p=4873